# MySQL before update trigger: how to get criteria in where clause when user uses UPDATE command

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am working with a trigger which will do check to user's inputted information before updating information in a table, say it's called "product". In the table "Product", there are 5 fields: Product number (VARCHAR), Product name(VARCHAR), Manufacturer(VARCHAR), Stock(INT), Price(VARCHAR).

So suppose users will update the "stock" (which is INT) in the table "Product" by the following command

```
UPDATE Product SET Stock = 10 WHERE ProdNo = 'P0036577';
```

and my program code for finishing my task is like below:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS price_update_trig //
CREATE TRIGGER price_update_trig
    BEFORE UPDATE ON product 
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    DECLARE oldPrice DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newPrice DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE totalRev DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
    SET oldPrice = substr(OLD.price, 2);
    SET newPrice = oldPrice - oldPrice * (NEW.stock - OLD.stock) / OLD.stock;
    SET totalRev = (SELECT sum(substr(price, 2) * stock) FROM product where ProdNo <> ***???** );
    SET totalRev = totalRev - oldPrice * OLD.stock + newPrice * NEW.stock;
    IF (totalRev > 17000.0) then
    SET NEW.price = concat('$', newPrice);
    else
    SET NEW.price = concat('$', oldPrice);
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

What I don't know how to do is that- how to get user's input in where clause, that means `ProdNo`('P0036577') and then put it into the where condition of the query for `totalRev`?

Comment: You are aware of `NEW.stock` and `OLD.stock` (which is actually the harder step) but not of `OLD.ProdNo`? Or does that not solve your problem (if you e.g. have queries like  `where ProdNo like 'P4%';` and you actually need the `P4%`?)

Comment: Side note: Don't use `varchar` for prices, use some numeric type.

Comment: The reason why I want to get ProdNo is because I want to find all items except the "ProdNo" inputted by user first, and eventually find the items which has the "ProdNo'.
That's not related to NEW.Stock and OLD.Stock

Comment: For the prices, since this is an assignment, so I have to strictly follow the spec given by the assignment....

Comment: I meant: `NEW.ProdNo` (and `OLD.ProdNo`) will contain the `ProdNo` of the row you are currently updating (following the exact same logic why `new.stock` and `old.stock` will contain the new/old value for `stock` of the row you are currently updating, which is why I mentioned those). It does not have to be the same string as in your where clause though, just the value of the row(s) that this where clause found. But it would be a very strange situation where you would need the value of the query itself, and especially if you are doing an assignment you might have misunderstood something.